# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present. XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, cors, xmlhttprequest

I got XmlHttpRequest object, and i'am trying to send long html data string to Asp Net Core, to make out of it content PDF file. But still getting CORS policies. Even-though i have "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in my header, it still an issue for me. Already tried everything with CORS. Installed cors for Asp net Core, nothing changed. Everything works fine if i use my HTML document from local.

Full error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://.../getInfoWindowPdf?' from
>   origin 'https://...' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

```
function infoWindowPdf()
{
    // Create request
    let http = new XMLHttpRequest(); //XMLHttpRequest XDomainRequest
    let url = backend + "getInfoWindowPdf?";

    // Add in htmlContent header
    let htmlContent = "<style>" + style +"</style>";

    // Get needed content
    let infoWindow = document.querySelector("#section-library-modal");

    //Waits for backend to create file after all open it and remove created temporary files
    http.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(http.readyState == 4)
        {
            window.open(backend + 'InfoPdf?filePath=C:\\Projects\\Web\\WebSections\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\pdf-export\\' + sectionName + ".pdf", '_blank');
            setTimeout(() => {getDBData('removepdf?filePath=C:\\Projects\\Web\\WebSections\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\pdf-export\\&filename=' + sectionName);}, 100);
        }
    };

    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); //application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    http.send(params);
}
```

My Asp Net Core Startup Config for CORS.

```
readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000",
                                    "http://localhost:5000/websections/getInfoWindowPdf?"
                                    ).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Edit:
Do not even try to work with Xmlhttprequest, if you want send some data to your backend project. Just use backend straight.

Comment: I've had the same kind of issue a few days ago.

Turn out, it's not a CORS issue; but that's how it's treated.

In my case, I had not started the asp.net core project (yes, I'm sometimes that dumb).

Comment: Don't think its something else than CORS. My button works if i open HTML file from local. But have this error if open the same HTML from Asp.

Comment: What's your CORS policy in the .net core app? You should have something in the startup.cs and/or an extension that sets your policy.

You should not have anything in your request, that's not needed.

Comment: edited my post.

Comment: Localhost:5000 is where your client is hosted, right ?

Comment: the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header must be set in the recieved answer, not the request.

Comment: DoctorPrisme yes. Seblor, how do i do that?

Comment: If you set CORS as you show in the post, the header is added automatically.

(Also, another question that might be unrelated : where does the "style" variable comes from ?)

Can you try by replacing "withOrigins()" by "allowanyorigins" ? This will help diagnose the issue.

Comment: I removed style from code, to make it shorter. So this is needed variable.

Comment: Place AllowAnyOrigin didn't help.. ((, so tired of this error......

Comment: Your error message, despite the truncating you did to it, shows that your origin starts `https://` but all the origins you allow start with `http://`. You appear to just made a typo in your list of acceptable origins.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the CORS nuget package.

   ```
   Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors
   ```
2. Add CORS services in ConfigureServices

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
     services.AddCors();
   }
   ```
3. In Configure method of Startup.cs file

   ```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   {
       app.UseCors(
           options => options.WithOrigins("http://example.com").AllowAnyMethod()
       );
       app.UseMvc();
   }
   ```

Comment: tried your exact variant, even i tried it before, still getting the same error.

Comment: if you use chrome, can you see what request / response headers are present in network tab after sending a request?

Comment: wait, response tab contains nothing.., and there is no response header at all, only request header