# .NET Core webapp serving SPA: Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core, cors, axios

The problem at it's most basic is this:

My '/api/users/githublogin' endpoint works fine if requested by a regular GET from the browser, or a regular GET from Postman. However, XHR, fetch, and axios all throw the same error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?etc' (redirected from 'https://localhost:5001/api/users/githublogin') from origin 'https://localhost:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

---

There are a couple of related questions out there, more related to Angular than React but the problem seems the same:

> [Enable CORS in ASP .NET Core 2.1 Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900055/enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-2-1-web-api)
>
> [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present. XmlHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55338224/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-xmlhttprequest)
>
> [.NET CORE 2.0 Angular 5: Allowing Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458631/net-core-2-0-angular-5-allowing-cors)
>
> [Local Javascript Fetch Post Request Fails with call to ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API. CORS is enabaled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464574/local-javascript-fetch-post-request-fails-with-call-to-asp-net-core-2-2-web-api)

I have implemented their answers without success.

---

Here follows my server side code concerning the CORS policy:

inside the ConfigureServices method:

```cs
            services.AddCors();
```

inside the Configure method:

```cs
app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowCredentials());
```

on my client side, a button calls this code:

```js
fetch('/api/users/githublogin');
```

---

Here follows the server log at the moment the failed request is made:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/api/users/githublogin application/json 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/api/users/githublogin application/json 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'web_server.Controllers.UsersController.GitHubLogin (web-server)'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware:Information: Executing endpoint 'web_server.Controllers.UsersController.GitHubLogin (web-server)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "GitHubLogin", controller = "Users"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult GitHubLogin(System.String) on controller web_server.Controllers.UsersController (web-server).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "GitHubLogin", controller = "Users"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult GitHubLogin(System.String) on controller web_server.Controllers.UsersController (web-server).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method web_server.Controllers.UsersController.GitHubLogin (web-server) - Validation state: Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method web_server.Controllers.UsersController.GitHubLogin (web-server) - Validation state: Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action method web_server.Controllers.UsersController.GitHubLogin (web-server), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult in 0.7161ms.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action method web_server.Controllers.UsersController.GitHubLogin (web-server), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult in 0.7161ms.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthHandler`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]][12]
      AuthenticationScheme: GitHub was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthHandler`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]:Information: AuthenticationScheme: GitHub was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action web_server.Controllers.UsersController.GitHubLogin (web-server) in 76.0766ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'web_server.Controllers.UsersController.GitHubLogin (web-server)'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action web_server.Controllers.UsersController.GitHubLogin (web-server) in 76.0766ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware:Information: Executed endpoint 'web_server.Controllers.UsersController.GitHubLogin (web-server)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 145.364ms 302 
      Request finished in 145.364ms 302
```

Nothing regarding CORS. In fact in the whole of the server log only this much mentions it:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[11]
      The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time. Configure the policy by listing individual origins if credentials needs to be supported.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Warning: The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time. Configure the policy by listing individual origins if credentials needs to be supported.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      CORS policy execution successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: CORS policy execution successful.
```

---

Now, it seems to me as though my server is correctly executing the actions that it is supposed to. That 302 Found (if I'm not mistaken) is basically a signal to the client to redirect to that github endpoint. So, if my server is not throwing a CORS related exception to the request (or however that works), and in fact has an AllowAnyOrigins flag set, why is the client receiving this error? And why does it not receive it when the browser makes the GET request?

I should note that this is a development server. As encouraged by the documentation, I am using the `spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000");` option. This is the one thing I could imagine is messing with me, seeing as technically the requests are coming from cross-origin (from port :3000 to port :5001), but I believe that it should not be a problem given the AllowAnyOrigins flag.

The api was built from a basic ASP.NET Core 2.2 webapi template. The client was built with create-react-app. They're both very boilerplate.

Could anyone help eludicate any of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here follows my server side code concerning the CORS policy...

That's irrelevant because you're making a request to the GitHub server. GitHub's  server policy is the only one that's relevant here, and you don't control it.

> My '/api/users/githublogin' endpoint works fine if requested by a regular GET from the browser, or a regular GET from Postman.

Correct, and that's because you own '/api/users/githublogin', whereas you **don't** own https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?etc.

And CORS is indeed locked down, by design, by GitHub: https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/330

---

Solution:

- Since CORS is only in play within the scope of a browser, rework your architecture and implement your own server-side web proxy so that the call to GitHub is made **server-side**; not **client-side** in a browser.

Here are some more resources about CORS:

- https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-cors-18ad6b478e2b
- https://www.sitepoint.com/working-around-origin-policy/
- [Creating a proxy to another web api with Asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42000362/109941)

Comment: Thank you kindly. I figured this out once I laid everything out in the post, but since I hadn't till that point I left it up for the potential value to the question+answer. That said, is there a reason my question was downvoted?

Comment: @jbarreto93: No. I'll cancel it out with an upvote.